# Get Purchase history Android in app billing version 2

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

How to check if user has already bought an item ? My product is managed and user can buy it once and i want that when ever user click on item after buying it, it should appear item even if he reinstall application...
right now clicking on the btnBuy a white block appears with the message ERROR and sub message that I've already purchased this item without anything else appearing.

secondly if there is a way then how can i test it?

My code is following. i am using in app billing version 2
in my main activity on create i call

`startService(new Intent(mContext, BillingService.class));
       BillingHelper.setCompletedHandler(mTransactionHandler);`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v.getId()==R.id.btnBUY)
    {

        if(BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()){

            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext, "com.test.buy"); 

            // android.test.purchased or android.test.canceled or android.test.refunded or com.blundell.item.passport
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG,"Can't purchase on this device");
             Toast.makeText(this, "Can't purchase on this device, Billing not Supprted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            hajj.setEnabled(false); // XXX press button before service started will disable when it shouldnt
        }

    }

 public Handler mTransactionHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Transaction complete");
        Log.i(TAG, "Transaction status: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.purchaseState);
        Log.i(TAG, "Item purchased is: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);

        if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.isPurchased()){
            showItem();
        }
    };
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by using in app billing version 3. it has more clear json response then v2

here 0 response code for OK
0:OK
and 7 Response Code for Item Already Owned
7:Item Already Owned

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with In-app Billing, but I suggest you to use the [version 3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html)! One feature that might help you is the following:

> All purchases are “managed” (that is, Google Play keeps track of the user's ownership of in-app products). The user cannot own multiple copies of an in-app item; only one copy can be owned at any point in time.

Comment: Dear my issue is to getpurchase history response!! before requesting for purchase i want to check that either user owned this item or not? it not then go for transaction else he will view item